# Probability inequality : $\Pr(X≤λ/2)≤4/λ$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Assume that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $λ$.
then prove this inequality
$$\Pr\left( X \le \frac \lambda 2 \right) \le \frac 4 λ$$

Answer (score 5):

Use Chebyshev's inequality

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]| \geq a) \leq {\mathbb{Var} \left[ X \right]  \over a^2} $$

For the Poisson distribution what is $ \mathbb{Var}  \left[ X \right] $?

The event $\{ X \leq \frac{\lambda}{2} \} \subset \{ X \leq \frac{\lambda}{2} \} \cup \{X \geq \frac{3\lambda}{2} \} = \{ |X - \lambda| \geq \frac{\lambda }{2}\}$.

Comment: Thanks ! that was very helpful.... I had forgoten that inequality

Comment: @AlirezaAlian I have changed my original answer.

Comment: this is more better.... the last one wouldn't help....
Thanks again :)

Comment: @AlirezaAlian No problem, I had actually misread the question. Did this solve the problem? I think in me changing the answer afterwards could possible remove it as the accepted answer.